# Wrap a FTP request in Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to perform a FTP request, wait till the file has downloaded and then close the FTP module. When both these actions have finished, then list the contents of a directory. At the moment, it is doing it in the opposite direction.

I have wrapped them in async and prepended the FTP with await. But the directory list is being logged first. Can spot the error in the async function?

```
(async function () {
  await Ftp.get("document.txt", "document.txt", err => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error("There was an error retrieving the file.");
    }
    console.log("File copied successfully!");

    Ftp.raw("quit", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
      }

      console.log("Bye!");
    });

  });
})()



// Read the content from the /tmp directory to check it's empty
fs.readdir("/", function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error("There was an error listing the /tmp/ contents.");
  }
  console.log('Contents of tmp file above, after unlinking: ', data);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, await only works with promises, and ftp.get apparently uses a callback instead of a promise. So you'll have to wrap ftp.get in a promise.

Second, your fs.readdir is outside of the async function, so it is not going to be affected by the await. If you need it to be delayed, then you need it to be inside the async function, after the await statement.

So put together that looks something like this:

```
(async function () {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Ftp.get("document.txt", "document.txt", err => {
      if (err) {
        reject("There was an error retrieving the file.")
        return;
      }
      console.log("File copied successfully!");

      Ftp.raw("quit", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    })
  });

  fs.readdir("/", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error("There was an error listing the /tmp/ contents.");
    }
    console.log('Contents of tmp file above, after unlinking: ', data);
  });
})()
```

Comment: This looks great, can I leave the readdir outside of the async function though?

Comment: What's the reason you want to do that?

Comment: I have a load more code to perform after this FTP function. Didn't want it all wrapped in an async function.

Comment: Any chance you could cast your eye over the main FTP program I wished to use and the issue with that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958602/ftp-in-aws-lambda-issues-downloading-files-async-await?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure what the hesitance is with wrapping it in an async function. If you want to have the code wait until the ftp.get is done, your options are: 1) put your code in an async function and `await` the promise 2) put your code in a callback function and explicitly pass that function into the `.then` callback of the promise 3) ditch promises and put your code in the callback function for ftp.get. I recommend #1 as it's the easiest to read.

Comment: Also you probably want to create separate `new Promise`s for the `get`, `quit` and `readdir` operations

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to separate things out. It looks like you wanted to save a file so I built this out with that in mind. I put each request into it's own promise. I don't think you need Ftp.raw. I am not sure if Ftp is the node library or simply the var name of another library.

```
const util = require("util");
const fs = require("fs");

const fsOpen = util.promisify(fs.open);
const fsWriteFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const fsClose = util.promisify(fs.close);

async function saveDocumentAndListDirectoryFiles() {
  let documentData;
  let fileToCreate;
  let listDirectoryFiles

  //We get the document
  try {
    documentData = await getDocument();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }

  // Open the file for writing
  try {
    fileToCreate = await fsOpen("./document.txt", "wx");
  } catch (err) {
    reject("Could not create new file, it may already exist");
    return;
  }

  // Write the new data to the file
  try {
    await fsWriteFile(fileToCreate, documentData);
  } catch (err) {
    reject("Error writing to new file");
    return;
  }

  // Close the file
  try {
    await fsClose(fileToCreate);
  } catch (err) {
    reject("Error closing new file");
    return;
  }

  // List all files in a given directory
  try {
    listDirectoryFiles = await listFiles("/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: No files could be found");
    return;
  }

  console.log(
    "Contents of tmp file above, after unlinking: ",
    listDirectoryFiles
  );
};

// Get a document
function getDocument() {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      await Ftp.get("document.txt", "document.txt");
      resolve();
    } catch (err) {
      reject("There was an error retrieving the file.");
      return;
    }
  });
};

// List all the items in a directory
function listFiles(dir) {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      await fs.readdir(dir, function(err, data) {
        resolve(data);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject("Unable to locate any files");
      return;
    }
  });
};

saveDocumentAndListDirectoryFiles();
```

Comment: Don't assign to undeclared (global?) variables, use function declarations instead.

Comment: Ahhhhh! Good catch. :)